# Neo4J Cypher multiple node queries

Tags: neo4j, cypher

My Graph pattern is below. (There are 2 loops (P1,P3) and (P2,P5)

```
P1 --- P2 --- P3 --- P4 --- P5
|      |      |             |
|      |      |             |
|       ------|---------------
|-------------|
```

What's the best way to express this in a Cypher? I have this one at the moment, but not sure if this is the most elegant/efficient one.

```
    MATCH (p1)-[c1:connected_to]->(p2)-[c2:connected_to]->(p3)-[c3:connected_to]->(p4)-[c4:connected_to]->(p5)-[c5:connected_to]->(p2), 
    (p3)-[c6:connected_to]->(p6) 
   RETURN p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6,c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query is certainly one way to represent your diagram, except that you seem to have an error. `p6` should probably be `p1`. And depending on your needs, you may not need to return every variable (by the way, you can return everything via `RETURN *`).

Also, your diagram does not show the directionality of the relationships, so it is not clear if your query actually represents your diagram.